# Do any Quidditch teams have coaches?

Tags: harry-potter

Madam Hooch is the flying instructor and referee for the Hogwarts students, but I don't recall ever hearing of the four different houses having Quidditch coaches for their house teams. Nor do I recall professional Quidditch coaches being referenced. I could certainly be wrong, but not having coaches for the biggest wizarding sport in the world, on either the amateur or professional level, seems odd. Am I just remembering incorrectly?

**Do any of the Quidditch teams in *Harry Potter* have coaches?**

<sub>I would prefer a canon-based answer from the books, JKR interviews, or Pottermore.</sub>

Comment: You are correct about Hogwarts' teams; their "coaches" seem to be their Captains...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's at least two references on Pottermore to (professional) international teams having coaches.

The [first](http://www.pottermore.com/en/daily-prophet/qwc2014/2014-06-06/bgr-v-nor) relates to an article supposedly written by Ginny Weasley for the Daily Prophet

> "Heartbroken **Norwegian coach [Oddvar Spillum](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Oddvar_Spillum)** had no comment for
>   reporters, but broken sobs. There can be no doubt that this has been a
>   deeply unlucky tournament for the usually outstanding Norwegians.
>   However irrational it may seem, many fans blame the Selma, a Norwegian
>   lake monster that the team brought as a mascot and which caused a
>   bloodbath at the opening ceremony. The Selma is tonight hiding in a
>   secret location."

And the [second](http://www.pottermore.com/en/daily-prophet/qwc2014/2014-06-06/bgr-v-nor) is in much the same vein;

> Snuka has previously been
>   dubbed an egoist by teammates and today’s actions will do little to
>   change his reputation.
>
> **Fijian manager and trainer [Hector Bolobolo](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hector_Bolobolo)**’s only comment after the
>   match was ‘I’m going to kill him'.

There's also a [glancing reference](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/history-of-the-quidditch-world-cup) by JKR in the new "History of the Quidditch World Cup" to the fact that *dragons* are not allowed on the quidditch stadium in any capacity, **including acting as team coach**.

> The rulebook concerning both on- and off-pitch magic is alleged to
>   stretch to nineteen volumes and to include such rules as ‘no dragon is
>   to be introduced into the stadium for any purpose including, but not
>   limited to, team mascot, **coach** or cup warmer’

Comment: Really nice answer -- +1 -- I love the bit about dragons not being allowed to coach Quidditch. Like, who in the world would have thought that a good idea to begin with? Thanks for the Pottermore detail. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I reckon some team did it to use the dragon as a weapon, I would.

Comment: The rules were probably changed after some one tried to pull an Air Bud with a dragon.

Comment: @Slytherincess Was that a rhetorical question? Obviously, the answer is that ***Hagrid*** would think it was a brilliant idea to train a dragon to be Quidditch coach.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and a hypogriff as a beater?

Comment: @WayneWerner God rest ye, merry hippogriffs!